# Creating database and tables directly from Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create the tables directly form Java instead of creating them using phpMyAdmin. The code looks like that runs smooth, but when the queries arrive, it gives some kind of error that I'm trying to identify and I'm not capable. Here's the code I've been trying:

```java
package filmoteca;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class GestionBDD {
    private static String datosConexion = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/";
    private static String baseDatos = "cine";
    private static String usuario = "root";
    private static String pass = "";
        private static String tabla = "pelicula";
    private Connection con;
    
    public GestionBDD() {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(datosConexion, usuario, pass);
                        try{
                            crearBDD();
                            crearTablas();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        
        public void crearBDD() throws Exception{
            String query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS"+ baseDatos +";";
            Statement stat = null;
            
            try{
                stat = con.createStatement();
                stat.executeUpdate(query);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(datosConexion+baseDatos, usuario, pass);
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                stat.close();
            }
        }
        
        public void crearTablas() throws Exception{
            String query = "USE DATABASE "+baseDatos+";"+
                    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+" "+tabla+"("
                    + "titulo VARCHAR(30), "
                    + "director VARCHAR(30), "
                    + "pais VARCHAR(30), "
                    + "duracion FLOAT, "
                    + "genero VARCHAR(30));";
            Statement stat = null;
            try{
               stat = con.createStatement();
               stat.executeUpdate(query);
               con = DriverManager.getConnection(datosConexion+baseDatos, usuario, pass);
                
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                stat.close();
            }
        }
        
}
```

Comment: When your code produces an error, than you should include the stacktrace of the exception in your question. However, it looks like the problem is a missing space after `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`. On a separate note, you should **not** call `USE DATABASE` from Java code, but use `Connection.setCatalog(String)` instead, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html

Comment: Also, in Java, you can only execute one SQL statement in one PreparedStatement.  Your USE and CREATE would throw a Java SQL error.

Comment: Probably you need to add a space after "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " because the + concatenates the string